# Select the max row per group - pandas performance issue

Tags: python, pandas, performance, greatest-n-per-group, pandas-groupby

I'm selecting one max row per group and I'm using `groupby`/`agg` to return index values and select the rows using `loc`.

For example, to group by `"Id"` and then select the row with the highest `"delta"` value:

```
selected_idx = df.groupby("Id").apply(lambda df: df.delta.argmax())
selected_rows = df.loc[selected_idx, :]
```

However, it's so slow this way. Actually, my i7/16G RAM laptop hangs when I'm using this query on 13 million rows.

I have two questions for experts:

1. How can I make this query run fast in pandas? What am I doing wrong?
2. Why is this operation so expensive?

---

[Update]
Thank you so much for @unutbu 's analysis!
`sort_drop` it is! On my i7/32GRAM machine, groupby+idxmax hangs for nearly 14 hours (never return a thing) however `sort_drop` handled it LESS THAN A MINUTE!

I still need to look at how pandas implements each method but problems solved for now! I love StackOverflow.

Comment: Related: [How do I find: Is the first non-NaN value in each column the maximum for that column in a DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349507/how-do-i-find-is-the-first-non-nan-value-in-each-column-the-maximum-for-that-co). Would be nice to also see how those answers' performance compares and scales.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The fastest option depends not only on length of the DataFrame (in this case, around 13M rows) but also on the number of groups. Below are perfplots which compare a number of ways of finding the maximum in each group:

If there an only a **few (large) groups**, `using_idxmax` may be the fastest option:
[image]

If there are **many (small) groups and the DataFrame is not too large**, `using_sort_drop` may be the fastest option:
[image]

Keep in mind, however, that while `using_sort_drop`, `using_sort` and `using_rank` start out looking very fast, as `N = len(df)` increases, their speed relative to the other options disappears quickly. **For large enough `N`, `using_idxmax` becomes the fastest option**, even if there are many groups.

`using_sort_drop`, `using_sort` and `using_rank` sorts the DataFrame (or groups within the DataFrame). Sorting is `O(N * log(N))` on average, while the other methods use `O(N)` operations. This is why methods like `using_idxmax` beats `using_sort_drop` for very large DataFrames.

Be aware that benchmark results may vary for a number of reasons, including machine specs, OS, and software versions. So it is important to run benchmarks on your own machine, and with test data tailored to your situation.

Based on the perfplots above, `using_sort_drop` *may be* an option worth considering for your DataFrame of 13M rows, especially if it has many (small) groups. Otherwise, I would suspect `using_idxmax` to be the fastest option -- but again, it's important that you check benchmarks on your machine.

---

Here is the setup I used to make the [perfplots](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import perfplot

def make_df(N):
    # lots of small groups
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(N//10+1, size=(N, 2)), columns=['Id','delta'])
    # few large groups
    # df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(N, 2)), columns=['Id','delta'])
    return df


def using_idxmax(df):
    return df.loc[df.groupby("Id")['delta'].idxmax()]

def max_mask(s):
    i = np.asarray(s).argmax()
    result = [False]*len(s)
    result[i] = True
    return result

def using_custom_mask(df):
    mask = df.groupby("Id")['delta'].transform(max_mask)
    return df.loc[mask]

def using_isin(df):
    idx = df.groupby("Id")['delta'].idxmax()
    mask = df.index.isin(idx)
    return df.loc[mask]

def using_sort(df):
    df = df.sort_values(by=['delta'], ascending=False, kind='mergesort')
    return df.groupby('Id', as_index=False).first()

def using_rank(df):
    mask = (df.groupby('Id')['delta'].rank(method='first', ascending=False) == 1)
    return df.loc[mask]

def using_sort_drop(df):
    # Thanks to jezrael
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381064/select-the-max-row-per-group-pandas-performance-issue/50389889?noredirect=1#comment87795818_50389889
    return df.sort_values(by=['delta'], ascending=False, kind='mergesort').drop_duplicates('Id')

def using_apply(df):
    selected_idx = df.groupby("Id").apply(lambda df: df.delta.argmax())
    return df.loc[selected_idx]

def check(df1, df2):
    df1 = df1.sort_values(by=['Id','delta'], kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
    df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['Id','delta'], kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
    return df1.equals(df2)

perfplot.show(
    setup=make_df,
    kernels=[using_idxmax, using_custom_mask, using_isin, using_sort, 
             using_rank, using_apply, using_sort_drop],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(2, 20)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    xlabel='len(df)',
    repeat=75,
    equality_check=check)
```

---

Another way to benchmark is to use [IPython %timeit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29280612/190597):

```
In [55]:  df = make_df(2**20)

In [56]: %timeit using_sort_drop(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 403 ms per loop

In [57]: %timeit using_rank(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.04 s per loop

In [58]: %timeit using_idxmax(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 15.8 s per loop
```

Comment: I once realised the fastest is `df = df.sort_values(by=['delta'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates('Id')`, is possible add to timings?

Comment: Sure. Running the benchmark now; will take some time.

Comment: @jezrael: Thanks for suggestion. Your approach (which I called `using_sort_drop` above) is indeed faster for moderately large DataFrames, especially if there are many small groups. But for very large DataFrames, `using_idxmax` will be faster.

Comment: "Moderately large" depends on the number of groups. With very few groups, `using_sort_drop` is advantageous until around len(df) = 100K. But if there are many small groups, it might still be the winner with len(df) around 100M. Thus, it depends a lot on the nature of your DataFrame. It's best to install perfplot and/or IPython and do some benchmarking.

Comment: Phew, you really know how to dish it out! Going to bookmark this, thanks.

Comment: Also good to note, correct me if I'm wrong, but sort stability may come in to play.  Wouldn't forcing sort to use `mergesort` be better than the default `quicksort`?

Comment: @piRSquared: I've been having trouble installing numba, so unfortunately I'm not able to add your method to the perfplot. But your %timeit result looks impressive.

Comment: @piRSquared: Thanks very much for the correction regarding sort stability. I should have been using `mergesort`. (Correcting this now...)

Comment: Thanks (-:  I like `perfplot` But I couldn't get a plot to appear in notebook.  I'll try harder.

Comment: Thanks for this - for me on a 20MM row df, sort / drop is absolutely trouncing the other methods.

Answer (score 5):

### Using Numba's jit

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit
def nidxmax(bins, k, weights):
    out = np.zeros(k, np.int64)
    trk = np.zeros(k)
    for i, w in enumerate(weights - (weights.min() - 1)):
        b = bins[i]
        if w > trk[b]:
            trk[b] = w
            out[b] = i
    return np.sort(out)

def with_numba_idxmax(df):
    f, u = pd.factorize(df.Id)
    return df.iloc[nidxmax(f, len(u), df.delta.values)]
```

---

Borrowing from [@unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50389889/2336654)

```
def make_df(N):
    # lots of small groups
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(N//10+1, size=(N, 2)), columns=['Id','delta'])
    # few large groups
    # df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(N, 2)), columns=['Id','delta'])
    return df
```

---

### Prime `jit`

```
with_numba_idxmax(make_df(10));
```

---

### Test

```
df = make_df(2**20)


%timeit with_numba_idxmax(df)
%timeit using_sort_drop(df)

47.4 ms ± 99.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
194 ms ± 451 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough @piRSqured, your code made my code run more than 5x faster