# Select max row per group in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe with multiple attributes, some are repeating. I want to select the rows based on the max value in one column - but return the row having that value (not the max of every column).
How??

Here's a sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Owner': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Amy',
                            'Steve','Kelly'],
                   'Make': ['Ford', 'Ford', 'Jeep',
                           'Ford','Jeep'],
                   'Model': ['Bronco', 'Bronco', 'Wrangler',
                            'Model T','Wrangler'],
                   'Max Speed': [80, 150, 69, 45, 72],
                  'Customer Rating': [90, 50, 91, 75, 99]})
```

this gives us:

[image]

I want the row having the max(customer rating) for each Make/Model.
Like this:
[image]

Note this is NOT the same as df.groupby(['Make','Model']).max()

**--> How do I do this?**

Comment: . [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Answer (score 1):

A variation of your answer using `idxmax`:

```
>>> df.loc[df.groupby(['Make', 'Model'])['Customer Rating'].idxmax()]
   Owner  Make     Model  Max Speed  Customer Rating
0    Bob  Ford    Bronco         80               90
3  Steve  Ford   Model T         45               75
4  Kelly  Jeep  Wrangler         72               99
```

Another solution **without** `groupby`:

```
>>> df.sort_values('Customer Rating') \
      .drop_duplicates(['Make', 'Model'], keep='last') \
      .sort_index()

   Owner  Make     Model  Max Speed  Customer Rating
0    Bob  Ford    Bronco         80               90
3  Steve  Ford   Model T         45               75
4  Kelly  Jeep  Wrangler         72               99
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer! I'm leaving the question up in case anyone else didn't recognize it as well.

Check out this post:
[Select the max row per group - pandas performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381064/select-the-max-row-per-group-pandas-performance-issue)

I couldn't tell from that post that it was in fact what I needed, but it is.
I tried two of them successfully:

```
def using_rank(df):
mask = (df.groupby(['Make', 'Model'])['Customer Rating'].rank(method='first', ascending=False) == 1)
return df.loc[mask]
df2 = using_rank(df)
df2
```

returns:

[image]

this also worked fine:

```
def using_sort(df):
df = df.sort_values(by=['Customer Rating'], ascending=False, kind='mergesort')
return df.groupby(['Make', 'Model'], as_index=False).first()
```